# Distributing raw msvcp.dll or installing vc_redist.exe

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, deployment

Deploying an app compiled with MSVC, should I include msvcp140.dll and vcruntime140.dll copy-pasted from VC folder with other .dll's, or distribiute vc_redist.exe installer, installing environment on each user computer?

What is the 'right' approach, and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no thumb rule or "right approach" for this scenario, rather pros and cons of choosing one over other. In my opinion, this depends on how the product/file is being deployed.

- If the file is not getting installed (extracted from a zip or runs before the installer), then placing the necessary redist in the same file is good enough. May be statically linking is better (?)
- If everything is getting installed via an installer, then installing the redistributables is cleaner way of doing this. There are already [merge modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/ide/redistributing-visual-cpp-files?view=vs-2017)  available to integrate with installer or even standalone executables

Won't recommend placing the necessary files in the folders where installer could be run as it's easier to maintain/update the redist files with each newer version ( of compilers and product)